# How can I find how insects are getting into my house?

Tags: insect

I have a problem with insects getting into my house which is strange because I have a modern, well-made house with air-tight construction and high-quality insulating windows.

Nevertheless one type of bug I consistently find in the house are leaf-footed bugs. I find them in three rooms: the master bath, one of the guest baths and the study. The study is on the opposite side of the house from the master bath.

I know that these bugs can flatten themselves and fit into narrow spaces, but the windows seem absolutely tight to me and I cannot understand how they are getting in through the windows, if that is where they are coming. How can I figure out their point of entry?

Comment: Perhaps two got in an open door or window and now they are multiplying? **I.E.** Not getting in but they  set up residence and made a happy home for their offspring.

Comment: They could be making their way down the vent pipe of your bathrooms and then into the study.  Are there any recessed light cans in the rooms?

Comment: If your house is tight I doubt there is a parade of them going in and out. One expectant mama may have gotten in and then....

Comment: Check your chimneys, plumbing vents, exhaust fan ducts, dryer ducts, soffit vents, gable vents, telco interfaces, behind doorbells/exterior lights, behind gas/power meters, power service entrance, mail slots, sump discharges, etc...

Comment: maybe what is getting into your house are eggs .... are you a gardener?

Comment: tiny cameras, everywhere